# CakePHP 2 - Pass referrer url for Auth component

Tags: cakephp-2.0

How can I pass the referrer url before the Auth component redirect me to the login page?
Currently I'm using this method to redirect user to the previous page after logging in

```
$this->Auth->redirect()
```

However, in my case sometimes that redirects me to the wrong location. (i.e I think in my case /users gets called along the way and it will redirect me to that location instead of where they came from). So I'm trying to see if passing the referrer url will help.

Thank you,
Tee

Answer (score 0):

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/authentication.html
Hope this will give a solution for you doubt

Answer (score 0):

```
$this->redirect($this->Auth->redirect());
```

worked for me.

After logging in, it goes to the page that I attempted while logged out.